# Applying a conditional statement on one column to achieve a result in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a script that will add 4 months or 8 months to the column titled "Date" depending on the column titled "Quarterly_Call__c". For instance, if the value in Quarterly_Call__c = 2 then add 4 months to the "Date" column and if the value is 3, add 8 months. Finally, I want the output in the column titled "New Date".

So far I am able to add the number of months I want using this piece of code:

```py
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

new_date = []
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.normalize()

for value in df['Date']:
        new_date.append(value + relativedelta(months=+4))
        df['New Date'] = new_date
```

[image]

However, as I mentioned, I would like this to work depending on the value in Quarterly_Call__c, so I tried writing this code:

```py
for i in df['Quarterly_Call__c'].astype(int).to_list():
        if i == 2:
                for value in df['Date']:
                        new_date.append(value + relativedelta(months=+4))
        elif i == 3:
                for value in df['Date']:
                        new_date.append(value + relativedelta(months=+8))
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Could you please recommend a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using lambda expressions to each of the rows on your DataFrame seems to be the most convenient approach:

```py
def date_calc(q,d):

    if q == 2:
        return d + relativedelta(months=+4)
    
    else:
        return d + relativedelta(months=+8)
        
df['New Date'] = df.apply(lambda x: date_calc(x['Quarterly_Call__c'], x['Date']), axis=1)
```

The date_calc function holds the same logic you posted in your question while taking the inputs as arguments, and the apply method of the DataFrame is used to calculate the 'New Date' column for each row where the variable x of the lambda expression represents a row of the DataFrame.

Keep in mind that the axis argument being specified to 1 is what makes sure that the function is applied for each row of the DataFrame rather than each column. More info about the apply method can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through row by row to access the row data, and calculate the new date.

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Quarterly_Call__c': [2,3,2,3], 
    'Date': ['2021-02-25', '2021-03-25', '2021-04-25', '2021-05-25']
})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['New Date'] = ''   #new empty column

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'Quarterly_Call__c'] == 2:
        df.loc[i, 'New Date'] = df.loc[i, 'Date'] + relativedelta(months=+4)
    if df.loc[i, 'Quarterly_Call__c'] == 3:
        df.loc[i, 'New Date'] = df.loc[i, 'Date'] + relativedelta(months=+8)
df['New Date'] = df['New Date'].dt.normalize()
```

Output

```
    Quarterly_Call__c   Date        New Date
0                   2   2021-02-25  2021-06-25
1                   3   2021-03-25  2021-11-25
2                   2   2021-04-25  2021-08-25
3                   3   2021-05-25  2022-01-25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try lambda functions on your dataframe. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

numbers = {'set_of_numbers': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers,columns=['set_of_numbers'])

df['equal_or_lower_than_4?'] = df['set_of_numbers'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if x <= 4 else 'False')

print (df)
```

You can check this link [[1]](https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/) for more information on how to apply if conditions on Pandas DataFrame.